# Dynamic Date time format conversion PHP to Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have some php date-time formats for which I need to get formatted values from mysql database.

Ex. 1 - php `date('Y-M-d H:i:s')` to mysql format would be `'%Y-%b-%d %H:%i:%s'`
Ex. 2 - php `date('d-M-Y H:i:s')` to mysql format would be `'%d-%b-%Y %H:%i:%s'`
Ex. 3 - php `date('d-Y-m H:i:s')` to mysql format would be `'%d-%Y-%m %H:%i:%s'`

So in all cases PHP date will changes on runtime and according to that date format mysql values need to get formatted.

Is there any ways to do it dynamically rather than specifying formats for all possible combinations?

Comment: How are you retrieving these? How are they stored in MySQL? If they are proper datetime columns, there may be ways to use `STR_TO_DATE()` on the mysql side or `strtotime()` on the PHP side. We can't be of much help without knowing how you are using these dates.

Comment: On Mysql side datetime format is fixed 'Y-m-d H:i:s', but upon retrieval I need different datetime combinations to set for all these values.

Comment: But how are you querying MySQL? This sounds like it may a simple use case where in PHP code you use `$mysqldate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($mixed_date_value))` to parse any usable date in PHP and immediately convert it to a string in MySQL's expected format.

Comment: let's say I have date-time '2017-12-26 10:50:22' stored in db and desired result format would be `'%Y-%d-%m %H:%i:%s'` or `'%M-%d-%Y %H:%i:%s'` or `'%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s'`, Desire date-time format is dynamic.